# How to call two API-s sequentially and keep return the data from both as a single Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have two APIs to call sequentially, with data returned from the first one used in the second one.

I've tried using `concatMap` inside the first call, and then to use the values returned in the second call, but when I subscribe to the observable, I get only the second call's data.

How can I get the data from both calls in a single observable?

```
this.dataService.getPlayerData("heunetik").pipe(
    concatMap(data => this.dataService.getLifetimeStats(data.payload.guid))
).subscribe(finalData => {
    console.log(finalData);
});
```

Reading up on the documentation, this is what seemed to make the most sense, but the examples are pretty confusing... :/

Comment: I have mentioned a better and clean solution, have a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you want to do some kind of inner map to combine the data:

```
this.dataService.getPlayerData("heunetik").pipe(
    switchMap(data => this.dataService.getLifetimeStats(data.payload.guid)
                          .pipe(map(innerData => [data, innerData])))
).subscribe(finalData => {
    console.log(finalData);
});
```

This would return the data in an array, first data set at 0 and second at 1.

switchMap is just my preference, doesn't really matter here between switch/concat/merge... They all have slightly different uses that matter with multiple emissions, but they'll all function identically here since these are all single emission observables.  I prefer switch because I think it's semantically more clear that I'm expecting single emissions, but opinions may differ on that point.

The high order maps used to provide a second argument that allowed for this combination but they removed it with rxjs 5 or 6 or so in favor of the inner map pattern to save on import size (which IMO was a bad decision... map arguments were useful more often than not and the inner map looks cluttered).

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the help! I think I'll start some online courses and attend a few RxJS related workshops to really "get" the essence. Observables are super useful, but can be quite complex to understand with the loads of pipe-able methods. :D

Comment: glad to help.  The learning curve is steep but once it clicks it clicks.

Comment: You can learn more about mergeMap, switchMap and concatMap in this course: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video

Answer (score 1):

we use the mergeMap also known as flatMap to map/iterate over the Observable values.

```
this.dataService.getPlayerData("heunetik").pipe(
    mergeMap(data => this.dataService.getLifetimeStats(data.payload.guid))
    .pipe(map(data2=>([data,data2])
).subscribe(finalData => {
    console.log(finalData);
});
```

Comment: I think you need one less `)` at the end of the second line and more `)` at the end of the third line